# Jest testing mocking default constructor and static constant

Tags: firebase, react-native, testing, jestjs

I want to test the following code:

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

export const canRequestPushNotificationPermission = async () => {
  return (
    (await messaging().hasPermission()) ===
    messaging.AuthorizationStatus.NOT_DETERMINED
  );
};
```

I noticed that in order to test `messaging()` I needed to mock the default constructor like so:

```
jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/messaging', () => {
  return () => ({
    hasPermission: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
  });
});
```

However this mocks the default constructor, how can I mock this constructor as well as the `messaging.AuthorizationStatus.NOT_DETERMINED`?

Answer (score -1):

use `spyOn` to mock the getter of the property of object
see https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

for example,

```
jest.spyOn(messaging, 'AuthorizationStatus', 'get').mockReturnValue({NOT_DETERMINED: 1})
```